# PostgreSQL - seed table with ids

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Is there an elegant way to fill table with dummy data in this manner.

I need to create this table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE counter(
    id int,
    userID int,
    dateCreated date
);
```

Seed sequence should be:

1. Id - from 1 to 100000000
2. UserId - 1 to 1000000, and for each 1M Id userid should start over from 1.
   So f.e id 1000000 userid 1000000, then when id passes 1M userid should start over from 1.
   f.e id = 1000001, userid = 1
3. dateCreated should also increase every 1M id, so when counter passes 1M the next date is added.
   F.e id = 1000000 dateCreated 1900.01.01, id = 1000001 dateCreated = 1900.01.02.

I've tried with generate_series, and thats fine for id.
Also with while loops, but it takes way too long.

Comment: Try combining both approaches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two `generate_series()` calls and some math to get populate the id column:

```
insert into counter(id, userid, datecreated)
select (t.userid - 1) * 100 + x.counter, 
        t.userid, 
        date '1900-01-01' + (t.userid - 1)
from generate_series(1,1000000) as t(userid)
  cross join generate_series(1,100) x(counter)
```

Comment: Would you really insert 100M rows at once, rather than, for example, looping 100 times and inserting 1M rows each time?

Comment: @MatBailie: why not? A loop is most probably slower

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This one is pretty fast. I would maybe add an index on id to be faster. 

Tho the solution is not really what i need. 
So userid should start from 1 and go to 1M. 

So lets say id goes to 100, and userId to 10 max.
I need id to go between 1..100 and each 10 id, userid should start from 1.
Also the date should increase each 10 rows.

Comment: @user256173: userid does go from 1 to 1000000 because of the `generate_series(1,1000000)`. If you want a different increment for the date, just change the formula e.g. using modulo

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks a lot! This solved it. 
Actually loop was slower when i've tested it!

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulo operator and integer division:

```
INSERT INTO counter(id, userid, datecreated)
SELECT
  num AS id,
  (num - 1) % 1000000 + 1 AS userid,
  date '1900-01-01' + (interval '1 day' * (num - 1) / 1000000) AS datecreated
FROM generate_series(1, 100000000) AS numbers(num);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4a285f2942c0dd66255f32df0eeee943

Comment: Yeah this is good! But the modulo on userid should be 1M instead of 10 :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I feel that creating 100M rows in one go is a lot, so I'd break it in to 100 batches of 1M.

I'd also use a `SERIAL` column to automatically take care of the `id` column.

Example Fiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=86fa35f68530860ac90ea70d5b9f7101

*(The fiddle is limited in space so uses dummy numbers, the version doing 100 batches of 1M is below...)*

```
do $$
begin

CREATE TEMP TABLE counter(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    userID int,
    dateCreated date
);

for batch in 0..99 loop

  INSERT INTO
    counter (
      userID,
      dateCreated
    )
  SELECT
    1000000 * batch + user_id,
    '1900-01-01'::date + batch * INTERVAL '1 day' 
  FROM
    generate_series(1, 1000000) user_id
  ;

end loop;

end; $$
```